# lambda expression meaning in xml configuratore

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I had this line of code i just wondering what this line of code does

```
Tracer.Initializer = () => XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

is it lambda expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's `Lambda` which specify zero input parameters with empty parentheses:

```
() => SomeMethod()
```

A lambda expression is an anonymous function that you can use to create delegates or expression tree types. By using lambda expressions, you can write local functions that can be passed as arguments or returned as the value of function calls. Lambda expressions are particularly helpful for writing `LINQ` query expressions.

To create a lambda expression, you specify input parameters (if any) on the left side of the lambda operator `=>`, and you put the expression or statement block on the other side. For example, the lambda expression `(x) => x * x` specifies a parameter that’s named x and returns the value of x squared

Note in your question the body of an expression lambda consists of a method call. However, if you are creating expression trees that are evaluated outside of the .NET Framework, such as in `SQL Server`, you should not use method calls in lambda expressions. The methods will have no meaning outside the context of the .NET common language run time.

Answer (score 0):

This lambda means that `XmlConfigurator.Configure()` will be called whenever `Tracer.Initializer()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, think of it as a method that can be stored in a variable.

You can also use parameters like

*(a) => foo.func(a)*